# CSS Transition working unreliably in IE10

Tags: css, reactjs, internet-explorer-10

My app uses React and I have it placing an onTransitionEnd listener on one of my divs.

```
<div className='side-banner' onTransitionEnd={onTransitionEnd}>
     <Content />
</div>
```

In my CSS file I have this:

```
transition: right 0.5s ease-out;
```

This handles a side banner sliding out from outside the screen into the screen. It works most of the time but occasionally (maybe 1/5 times on average) the side banner will show up already on the screen after a refresh. Of course, without the transition, no onTransitionEnd will fire, which causes trouble within my app.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: As a workaround, I would try to force so called reflow by accessing the `offsetWidth` property of the transition-subject element _before_ toggling the transition.

Comment: Hey Marat, how would you implement that exactly?

Comment: `element.offsetWidth;` where `element` is the element to be transitioned.